# ModuleNotFoundError when importing in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am a beginner in python and I have pulled code from a github repo to work on. But it is giving me the following error at the line `from src.splendor import SplendorGame` in `test_splendor.py`:

```
/usr/bin/python3 "/Users/b.w.h/Documents/JHU/Google Game Theory Development/Splendor-AI/test/test_splendor.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/b.w.h/Documents/JHU/Google Game Theory Development/Splendor-AI/test/test_splendor.py", line 16, in <module>
    from src.splendor import SplendorGame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

And the file structure looks as follows:
[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOReu.png)

I know it has something to do with the python interpreter path but I am not sure how to fix it. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `src` is non-importable. In the README, do the maintainers have instructions for how to run tests?

Comment: I didn't see any instructions for running. The `test_splendor.py` has a line to construct path before importing: `sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/..')`

Comment: Do they have a `setup.py`? If so, can you add that into the question?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see a `setup.py`

Comment: Can you link to the github repo?

Comment: It's a private repo...

Comment: I'll need a bit more info to be able to help, but tests using `from src import...` syntax are usually not structured properly. A virtual environment should be able to install the module through the use of a `setup.py` and run tests with one of many python testing suites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're two optional ways:

1. Add the following code before import sentence in `test_splendor.py`:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append("./")
   ```

   Then **click the green button** to run python file in Terminal.
2. In `launch.json`, add the following configurations:

   ```
   "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH":"${workspaceFolder}"
   },
   "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
   ```

   This only works when you **Run without debugging(Ctrl+F5)**, click the green button will also throw the error.

[image]